# How to disable css module file suffix ".module" in Next.js config?

Tags: webpack, next.js, css-modules

I use css modules in 100% of cases, so why write the word .module in the file name every time? If I were manually configuring webpack I would change this suffix, but how do I do it in next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with same problem and after a few hours, I found a solution. If you want to use css-modules in 100 % cases, you must edit webpack config in your next.config.js:

I did is by this code:

```
const isTwoRegexEqual = (x, y) => {
   return (
      x instanceof RegExp &&
      y instanceof RegExp &&
      x.source === y.source &&
      x.global === y.global &&
      x.ignoreCase === y.ignoreCase &&
      x.multiline === y.multiline
   );
}

const getConfigToAcceptSassFilesWithoutModuleSuffix = (config) => {
   return {
      ...config,
      module: {
         ...config.module,
         rules: config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
            if (rule.oneOf) {
               return {
                  ...rule,
                  oneOf: rule.oneOf.map((loaderSettings) => {
                     if (
                        (!Array.isArray(loaderSettings.test) && isTwoRegexEqual(loaderSettings.test, /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/))
                        || (Array.isArray(loaderSettings.test) && loaderSettings.test.filter((test) => isTwoRegexEqual(test, /(?<!\.module)\.(scss|sass)$/ )).length > 0)
                     ) {
                        return {
                           ...loaderSettings,
                           test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                        }
                     }

                     return loaderSettings;
                  })
               }
            }
            return rule;
         })
      }
   }
};
```